# Can't seem to find what's wrong with this piece of code... F#

Tags: list, f#

I have checked everywhere and I can't seem to locate the problem. The compiler is giving me this error: "`error FS0039: The value or constructor 'dotProduct' is not defined`". But dotProduct is currently defined.

Visual Studio 2010 is also highlighting the second let (`let rec dotProductAux list1 list2 acum =`) saying that the expression is unfinished.

```
let dotProduct list1 list2 =
    let rec dotProductAux list1 list2 acum =
        match list1 ,list2 with
          | [],l | l,[] -> acum
          | head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2 -> let updated = (head1 * head2) + acum
                                              (dotProductAux tail1 tail2 updated)
```

This code multiplies and adds two list like this:

```
dotProduct [1;4;7] [3;4;1];;   //(1*3) + (4*4) + (7*1)
```

I'm fairly new to F# and can't seem to get this code right. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of `dotProduct` contains the definition of `dotProductAux`, but no actual expression. You need to actually call `dotProductAux` (i.e. you're missing the call `dotProductAux list1 list2 0` after the `let rec`).

<s>Furthermore the case `| [],[]| l,[] -> accum` will cause an error because the second pattern binds the variable `l`, while the first does not. You can fix that by replacing `l` with `_`, since you don't actually need it.</s> (Apparently you've already fixed this in an edit).

Comment: I created a call to the dotProductAux and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!